# Hasura GraphQL allows for proper POLP Write (insert) privileges to work on Views with .NET application using PostgreSQL but not with SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql, graphql

Here is info about our technical development environment :

- Hasura GraphQL v2.6.2-pro.1
- SQL Server Management Studio(SSMS) 19.0.2
- Docker Engine v20.10.23
- PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
- .NET 6
- C# 10

One of our .NET application uses PostgreSQL as the backend database. Another .NET application uses SQL Server as its backend.

In both applications we are only inserting data into tables (therefore, there is no update/delete functionality needed).

For the .NET application that uses PostgreSQL, we wanted to adhere to good security practices (e.g Principle of Least Privileges(POLP)) in our implementation, therefore,

1. We created views for each of our application tables in the PostgreSQL database
2. We created a trigger for each view
3. We created an insert function that would be associated with each of the aforementioned triggers so that we can insert data via the view as opposed to the database
4. We only "track" the views in Hasura GraphQL (but not the corresponding tables)

Essentially, we only insert via the view's triggers (not directly to the tables themselves) which is a good security practice.

It works quite well. We have Hasura GraphQL mutation string that are constructed and interpolated by the C# code.

Deployment and testing of said C# applications that used PostgreSQL worked quite well.

For our .NET application that uses SQL Server database, we wanted to adhere to similar good security practices.

1. We created views for each of our application tables in the SQL Server database
2. We created triggers for each view that would do an insert
3. We only "track" the views in Hasura GraphQL (not the corresponding tables)

We had the same idea with these .NET applications that use SQL Server.
However, Hasura GraphQL does not allow us to insert data via views.
Essentially, we can not insert data via the views if will only give the .NET application write (insert) privileges.

The error being thrown by the application is:

> Errors (1) 1: no mutations exist

However, if we grant the .NET application admin role in Hasura GraphQL, then it inserts via the view.

But we want to adhere to proper Principle of Least Privileges (POLP) practices.

Why is it that Hasura GraphQL allows for proper POLP write (insert) privileges to work on views in a .NET application using PostgreSQL, but not with SQL Server?